# Need Suggestions: Setting up QA software automation for autonomous vehicles

Tags: automated-testing

I need some inputs how to setup QA software automation infrastructure for testing the build programs for autonomous vehicles. The idea is to bring in automation frameworks to validate modules, probably converting the code from OpenCV, ROS to python wrappers, then validate it with data driven testing.

I would be glad if any inputs could be given on this front.

Comment: We'll need some clarifications- what do you need to test ? end to end tests ? what do you mean by " testing the build programs" - compilation and building of code ?

Comment: @Rsf - the requirement is like, the software to be developed for an autonomous vehicle with OpenCV/ROS where majority of coding is in C++. This would include multiple modules to get the vehicle driven in defined paths. So the requirement is to evaluate each of the module with an automation framework. Each of the module would be an API for the decision making system. CI/CD to be followed, where is there would daily code checks and there should be jobs setup in jenkins. Majority of the testing would be binary/images/texts file comparisons with respect to reference data sets.

Comment: @Rsf - To being with it would be a module wise automation, then future state to be and end to end testing involving multiple systems. This would be done on Linux machines. I'm thinking of using JIRA + Python + Robot Framework + Jenkins + Klaros(Test Management). Robot Framework might help both with API/Embedded/UI testing. Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Great questions and interesting area, but the question is too wide. Can you break you them to smaller more precise questions ? For example using Robot with Python in your context (search for previous answers first), using Python for image comparison tests etc.